# Variable value in while True

Tags: python

```
while True:
    lenreplay = len(mail.reply())
    print(lenreplay)
    if len(mail.reply()) > lenreplay:
        print('done')
        print(mail.reply()[0])
```

At some point the length of `mail.reply()` will no longer be what it was before. I want the `if` to work. Please note that `if` here in my code doesn't always work. It only works if the computing process was between `lenreplay = len(mail.reply())` and `if len(mail.reply()) > lenreplay:`. I want for it to always work.

`mail.reply()` is a group of emails inside a list. If I sent an email that list will get a new length, which means it will become bigger than it was before.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is `len(mail.reply())` checking the current number of replies to some mail? And you want this loop to continue until an additional reply has been received?

Comment: @Grismar even if I did that there is a possibility for the email to come after sleep and after 'if'

Comment: Of course, which is when the loop repeats, so it's caught immediately.

Comment: @Grismar yes the important point was to add a new loop then there is even no need for sleep()

Comment: Typically, you add something like `sleep()` to avoid your script taking up a lot of processing time only to obsessively check for new mail - also, the server that needs to check for new replies will be heavily taxed. You should consider how quickly you need to respond to the new reply arriving, and adjust the timeout to that, but having a timeout is a good idea in general, even if it has to be small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `len(mail.reply())` checking the current number of replies to some mail? And you want this loop to continue until an additional reply has been received? Why not put `lenreplay = len(mail.reply())` outside the loop and add a small delay (like `time.sleep(1)`) to avoid constantly checking?

I.e.:

```
from time import sleep

number_of_replies = len(mail.reply())
while True:
    print(number_of_replies)
    sleep(1)  # maybe wait a second here, to avoid spamming the call
    if len(mail.reply()) > number_of_replies:
        print('done')
        print(mail.reply()[0])
        break
```

I renamed the variable, since its previous name didn't make that much sense. Also, I added `break` to exit the loop; if you didn't have `break` because you want this to run forever, this would work:

```
from time import sleep

while True:
    number_of_replies = len(mail.reply())
    while True:
        print(number_of_replies)
        sleep(1)
        if len(mail.reply()) > number_of_replies:
            print('done')
            print(mail.reply()[0])
            break
```